# Swift Retreive Firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

The following data in the Firebase Database:

```
{
  "schedule": {
      "Week 1": {
        "active": "true"
      },
      "Week 2": {
        "active": "true"
      },
      "Week 3": {
        "active": "false"
      },
      "Week 4": {
        "active": "true"
      },  
      ...
   }
}
```

I want to retrieve all the Weeks where the active is true only.
I am setting the Firebase reference as such:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Schedule")
```

and then doing the following:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        //
        print("Count: ", snapshot.childrenCount)

        for _ in snapshot.children {
                print("\(snapshot.value)")
        }

    })
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Optional({
      "Week 1" =     {
           active = 1;
       };
       "Week 2" =     {
           active = 1;
       };
       "Week 3" =     {
           active = 0;
       };
       "Week 4" =     {
           active = 1;
       };
       ...
}
```

Can someone please suggest how I can get just the weeks where active is set to true which needs to be loaded in an array of type string :

```
var weeksActive = [String]()
```

Comment: This is covered in the Firebase Getting Started guide [Working With Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in the Filtering Data section. However, the old Firebase documentation is WAY better than the current so check out [Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) in the Querying data section. They are outdated but the explanation and examples will be a help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you can use `queryOrdered(byChild:)` and `queryEqual(toValue:)` like this.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Schedule").queryOrdered(byChild: "active").queryEqual(toValue : true)

ref.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot) in

    print("Count: ", snapshot.childrenCount)
    for child in snapshot.children {
        print("\((child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value)")
        //To get week you need to access key
        print("\((child as! FIRDataSnapshot).key)")
    }
})
```

Comment: The output is as follows: Count:  4
Optional({
    active = 1;
})
Optional({
    active = 1;
})
Optional({
    active = 0;
})
Optional({
    active = 1;
})

Comment: The output is as follows: Count:  4
Optional({
    active = 1;
})
Optional({
    active = 1;
})
Optional({
    active = 0;
})
Optional({
    active = 1;
})      I wish to get a list as such: Week 1, Week 2, Week 4 since those are the ones with active set to true and not the active = 1

Comment: @iosforme Check the edited answer and you can get week using key. If you still face issue then you need to show how you are adding that child in `Schedule`.

Comment: @iosforme Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Here Is The Code

1) Create New Swift Page in The Name as `Schedule.swift`

2) Inside `Schedule.swift` Page Use The Below Code

```
import UIKit
class Schedule: NSObject
{
   var weeks: String?
   var active: String?
}
```

3) In `ViewController.Swift` Page or Other Page Use This Code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var ShceduleList = [Schedule]()
    var ref = FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: Uint!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
       self.FetchSchedule()
    }

    fun FetchSchedule()
    {
       refHandle = ref.child("schedule").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot) in
          if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
          {
               let Schedule = Schedule()
               Schedule.setValuesForKeyWithDictionary(dictionary)
               self.ScheduleList.append(Schedule)
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                print("Schedule List: \(self.ScheduleList)")
               })
          } 
       })
    }
}
```

Here I Have Added Code Upto Appending Data's To Array You Just Need To Validate Values As Per Your Needs Before Appending To ScheduleList Array.

Comment: This isn't the answer of question, OP want week with active are true, and what you have done is simply observe for `ChildAdded`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the code for the problem mentioned above. First take the item value as FIRDatabaseSnapshot.value!. Then append it into weeksActive.

```
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            //
            print("Count: ", snapshot.childrenCount)

            for item in snapshot.children {
                    print("\(item as! FIRDataSnapshot).value)")
                   let week = item as! FIRDataSnapshot).value!

            }

        })
```

Comment: Nope. Not correct and doesn't address the OP question.

Comment: What is correct address please explain. It will help others.

Comment: The question asks *I want to retrieve all the Weeks where the active is true only.* This answer retrieves all nodes in ref, then iterates over them. It doesn't return only the ones where active is true.