# Return two arrays from observeSingleEvent

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have questions and answers in Firebase Realtime Database, which I need to be downloaded and put in to arrays. I have created a function which takes a parameter and should return two arrays

```
let data = fetchQuestions(category: "Animals")
qAni = data.ques
aAni = data.ans
```

fetchQuestions method:

```
func fetchQuestions(category: String) -> (ques: [String], ans: [String]) {
        var q = [String]()
        var a = [String]()
        ref.child("QA/Category").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
            for (k, v) in value! {
                if k == category {
                    let QA = v as! NSArray
                    for i in QA {
                        let question = i as! [String: String]
                        q.append(question["question"]!)
                        a.append(question["answer"]!)
                    }
                    return (q, a)  ** Unexpected non-void return value in void function
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I have tried to use dispatch group, but then I receive a different error.

Comment: You are currently returning from the completion block of `observeSingleEvent` and its return type is void What you need is you need to create completionHandler with your `fetchQuestions`. Also instead of using `NSArray` with swift use Swift native array. Also instead of maintaining two array maintain one array with custom objects of struct or class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently returning from the completion block of `observeSingleEvent` and its return type is `void`, What you need is you need to create `completionHandler` with your `fetchQuestions`. Now with Swift instead of using `NSArray` use Swift native array. Also instead of maintaining two array maintain one array with custom objects of struct or class.

So first create one `struct` like this.

```
struct Category {
    let question: String
    let answer: String
}
```

Now make completionHandler with your `fetchQuestions` like this way.

```
func fetchQuestions(category: String, completion: @escaping([Category]) -> Void) {
    var array = [Category]
    ref.child("QA/Category").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        for (k, v) in value! {
            if k == category {
                let QA = v as! [[String:String]]
                for i in QA {                       
                    let que = i["question"]!
                    let ans = i["answer"]!
                    array.append(Category(question: que, answer: ans))
                }                    
            }
        }
        completion(array)
    })
}
```

Now call `fetchQuestions` this way.

```
self.fetchQuestions(category: "Animals") { categories in
    //access categories here
    print(categories)
}
```

**Note:** Instead of comparing value in for loop you can also use `queryEqual(toValue:)` with your request to get specific result check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41457179/6433023) for more details on it.

Comment: How do I then exactly access the questions and answers? When I `print(categories)` I get:
[Answer_This.GameViewController.CategoryQA(question: "What does a camels hump contain?", answer: "fat, water, cartilage, salt"), Answer_This.GameViewController.CategoryQA(question: "How many fingernails does a chimpanse have on its right hand?", answer: "5, 4, 6, 7")
... and so forth

Comment: @GlennHerping If you are displaying this in tableview then you can access this array in `cellforRow` like this way `cell.lblQuestion.text = self.categories[indexPath.row].question` and for answer  `cell.lblAnswer.text = self.categories[indexPath.row].answer`

Comment: I need them to be in two arrays (questions and answers) because they're to be shown on labels and buttons.

Comment: Found the answer to the comment! Looped through the indices like this: `for i in categories.indices {
print(categories[i].question)
}`

Comment: @GlennHerping No need to create new array now at any place you want access question of specific index you can get it this way `categories[index].question` and answer  `categories[index].answer`

Comment: I have multiple categories and want to keep all questions and answer in the case user plays multiple games in one session, and it is also possible that it should be all categories. Wouldn't it then be easier to have them in other arrays?

Comment: @GlennHerping With your question Currently you are storing all type of category’s question and answer in same question and answer array then you can do same way single Category array also, there is one way with two struct like `struct Category { let categoryType: String, let games: [Game] }` and Game struct having question and answer `struct Game { let question: String, let answer: String }`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are returning a value from a closure instead you should use different closure for that. Try it:

```
func fetchQuestions(category: StringcompletionBlock:@escaping (_ ques:[String], _ ans :[String]) -> ()) {
    var q = [String]()
    var a = [String]()
    ref.child("QA/Category").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        for (k, v) in value! {
            if k == category {
                let QA = v as! NSArray
                for i in QA {
                    let question = i as! [String: String]
                    q.append(question["question"]!)
                    a.append(question["answer"]!)
                }

            }
          return completionBlock(q,a)
        }
    })
}
```

> @escaping is required :   when the closure is passed as an argument to
>   the function, but is called after the function returns.