# Get parent node where nested property equal some value in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Before writing question I would say that I'm new in iOS development and in firebase too :) That's why I apologize in advance for a silly question :)

I have the next structure of data in firebase (for example):

```
- users
-- id:123
--- name: Roy
--- age: 28
--- isAdmin: true
-- id:124
--- name: Bill
--- age: 35
--- isAdmin: false
-- id:125
--- name: Mike
--- age: 25
--- isAdmin: true
```

I want to write request to firebase and get all node of user with all nested fields where **isAdmin == true**.

I can get all users and make loop through all collection of users and check field **isAdmin** in each iteration but it's bad way. Maybe firebase give opportunity to get this data in one line of code?

If not **id** field I have done it fast by self but **id** create problem to do it because they are different for each user and I can't write correct path in child() function.

Comment: Here id is `childByAutoId` ?

Comment: @NiravD yes it's

Comment: Check this answer of my https://stackoverflow.com/a/41457179/6433023 you just need to change `active` key to `isAdmin` in `queryOrdered(byChild:)` with your firebase reference

Comment: @NiravD Thank you! It works! :)

Comment: Welcome mate :) Glad it works for you :)